# Python 3.4 Xpath How to Access 2 Associated Elements

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath

xml example:

```
<row>
   <entry>
      <para>
           <location>Seattle</location>
      </para>
    </entry>
    <entry>
          <para>Washington</para>
    </entry>
</row>
```

I need to loop through xml files and find all locations and associated states and output to a report. How do I do that using xpath? I can't figure it out?

I can get location no problem - but I have looked at xpath tutorials and examples til' my head is spinning:

```
locations = program.xpath('.//location')

for location in locations:
    location = location.text
```

I would prefer to use xpath but any easy to understand solution (or a good site) would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Edit:

I tried this example from [Python 2.7 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643094/python-version-2-7-xml-elementtree-how-to-iterate-through-certain-elements-of)

```
for patient in root:
    patient_code =  patient.find('PatientCharacteristics').find('patientCode')
    if patient_code.text == code:
            for visit in patient.find('Visits'):
                    visit_date = visit.find('VisitDate')
                    if visit_date.text == date:
                        swol28 = visit.find('DAS').find('Joints').find('SWOL28')
                        if swol28.text:
                            visit.find('DAS').find('Joints').set('SWOL28', new_swol28)


program = setupTree.getroot()

for row in program:
            location =  row.find('entry').find('para').find('location ')
            locationText = location .text
            state=  row.find('entry').find('para')
            stateText = state.text
```

But it didn't work in 3.4? The returned error was - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: How does location linked to country element? Is it one `row` element always holds a pair of `entry` elements, each for location and the corresponding country?

Comment: Yes har07 (ty for responding) - I believe that is the case as far as I have seen. This is actually about 1000,000+ files so...

Comment: Judging from the `xpath()` method being used, you're using `lxml` here, right?

Comment: Yes I am - from lxml import etree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one `<row>` always only contains the two `<entry>` elements, then you can get state text from *the last* `<entry>` in each `<row>`, like so :

```
for row in root.findall('.//row'):
    location = row.find('entry/para/location').text

    # get state from the last `entry/para` of current `row`
    state = row.findall('entry/para')[-1].text
```

Comment: Quick demo using `ElementTree` : https://eval.in/533993 (`lxml` is compatible with `ElementTree`)

Comment: It works - ty - I had to figure out some stuff because the rows are more deeply nested than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the level of detail you've provided, I would suggest you take a look at ElementTree iteration utilities.

For example, something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse("yourfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

locations = []
for elt in root.iter("location"):
    locations.append(elt)
```

Where "location" is the common tag you are interested in.

This will retrieve any and all elements with the tag "location" in the tree, regardless of their position in the hierarchy. Unless you provide a consistent location of where each desired element is located, this is what I would suggest.

Comment: Ty for responding - I can already get location - I am trying to figure out how to get the associated state from the Entry/para element path