# Python 3.4: Moving Through XML Tree

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python and have never worked with xml so excuse my lack of expertise.

I have a fairly long text file with an xml inside of it:

```
- - - - Some Text Until This Point — — — - - - 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record xmlns="http://www.south.org/>
   <Patient>
     <ID>4</ID>
     <Status>Good</Status>
     <Pain>8</Pain>
   </Patient>
   <Hospital>
     <Name>South Center.</Name>
     <Address>1234 Main Ave New York NY 4567 United States</Address>
     <Phone>+1 (123) 456 7890</Phone>
     <Email>emergency@southcenter.com</Email>
   </Hospital>
   <Insurance>
     <Name>Health First</Name>
     <Phone>+1 (123) 456 7890</Phone>
   </Insurance>
   <Admitted>
     <Date>2000-11-8t7:24:02</Date>
     <Injury>Arm</Injury>
     <Location>7</Location>
   </Admitted>
   <Place>
     <Room>
      <Number>28</Number>
      <Wing>East</Wing>
     <Name>John Smith</Name>
    </Room>
  </Place>
</Record>

- - - - - - - - - - - Some more Text - - - - - — - - - - - — - - - -
```

I am trying to get the values under the "Admitted" tag and the value for name under the "Place" tag and save them to local variables. I know this question is very similar to the one listed below but I still can't seem to get it right.

[Python version 2.7: XML ElementTree: How to iterate through certain elements of a child element in order to find a match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643094/python-version-2-7-xml-elementtree-how-to-iterate-through-certain-elements-of)

Here is the code that I have so far, it only contains the xml code while ignoring the opening and closing of the text file:

This is the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

# Slice the xml portion of the text file
myxml = textfile[textfile.index(<"?xml):(textfile.index("</Record")+8)]
root = fromstring(myxml)

for admitted in root:
    date = admitted.find('Admitted').find('Date').text
    injury = admitted.find('Admitted').find('Injury').text
    loc = admitted.find('Admitted').find('Location').text
    print(date)
    print(injury)
    print(loc)
```

I will be grateful for any advice on the matter and thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use minidom for parsing xml code. It is really easy. The code below parses out the MANUFACTURER part. See example below.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import re

xmlstring="""
... and listening to slow jazz <---should not be here
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST> 123.00</COST>
   </PART>
foo <---should not be here
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
bar  <---should not be here
      <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
      <COST> 160.00</COST>
   </PART>
</PARTS>"""

#Clean file to use only xml code otherwise minidom wont work
l=[]

for line in xmlstring.split('\n'):
    newxml=re.search(r'<..*>$',line)
    if newxml:
        l.append(line.strip())
newxml='\n'.join(l)
#Minidom
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(newxml)
Topic=dom.getElementsByTagName('PARTS')
i = 0
for node in Topic:
    alist=node.getElementsByTagName('MANUFACTURER')
    for a in alist:
        Title= a.firstChild.data
        print Title

#Output would be ASUS and ATI
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `dom.findall()` of etree. Be sure to account for the undeclared namespace as shown in the braces definition: `{...}`

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xmlfile = 'path/to/xml/file.xml'
dom = ET.parse(xmlfile)

admitted = dom.findall('{http://www.south.org/}Admitted/*')

date = []; injury = []; loc = []
for i in admitted:    
    if 'Date' in i.tag: date.append(i.text)
    if 'Injury' in i.tag: injury.append(i.text)
    if 'Loc' in i.tag: loc.append(i.text)

print(date)
print(injury)
print(loc)

place = dom.findall('{http://www.south.org/}Place/*/*')

number = []; wing = []; name = []
for i in place:    
    if 'Number' in i.tag: number.append(i.text)
    if 'Wing' in i.tag: wing.append(i.text)
    if 'Name' in i.tag: name.append(i.text)

print(number)
print(wing)
print(name)
```

**Output**

```
# ['2000-11-8t7:24:02']
# ['Arm']
# ['7']
# ['28']
# ['East']
# ['John Smith']
```

Comment: I was looking to use the ElementTree API, since I am a novice and the xml is embedded within a textfile. My only problem seems to be that I can't get root to move correctly to it's children

Comment: You need to use [iter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#19.7.1.3) but must account for the undeclared namespace in xml.

Comment: The namespace! Wow, thank you that fixed the problem :)